# MATLAB: fzero with a matrix as input to function?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find the value x for a function f(x,y) that produces the function value 0 for a given y. In Matlab I write a small function handle, e.g.

```
minme = @(y,x) y-x.^2;
```

and use the fzero function to find that value of x, call it x*.

So e.g.

```
fzero(@(x) minme(5,x),1)
```

works great. However, now I want to find x* for a large vector of values of y, called Y. Putting

```
minme(Y,x)
```

for some value of x works.

Now I was trying something like

```
fzero(@(x) minme((3:1:5),x),1)
```

and
fzero(@(x) minme(Y,x),1)

but that produces an error:
*??? Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.
Error in ==> fzero at 333
elseif ~isfinite(fx) || ~isreal(fx)*

Does anybody know whether there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out

```
arrayfun(@(i) fzero(@(x) minme(y(i),x),1),1:numel(y))
```