# fzero with a matrix and solution of previous fzero as an input

Tags: matlab, input, matrix, root

This is an evolution of the question asked by Immo [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061486/matlab-fzero-with-a-matrix-as-input-to-function/22632694#22632694)

We have a function f(x,y) and we are trying to find the value of x (x*) for a function f(x,y) that produces the function value 0 for a given Y, where Y is a large vector of values.

```
x* = arrayfun(@(i) fzero(@(x) minme(y(i),x),1),1:numel(y))
```

What if now I would like to use the x* solution of the arrayfun to find another fzero of the second equation, lets say minme2, that also depends on the same large vector of values Y.

```
minme2 = @(y,x*, x) x - Y + x* + x* ./ (const1 * (const2 - x*))
```

Moreover I would like my solutions to dynamically depend on the interval I am selecting for the fzero solution, rather than the initial guess. Instead of 1 I would like my solutions to be found in between:

```
x0 = [0, min(const1, x*)];
```

I would appreciate answers how can I solve the minme2 as currently I am facing errors.

Comment: What errors are you facing? Matlab errors or conceptual errors? Also please note `x*` is not a valid variable name in matlab.

Comment: Thank you Alan. I should write the upper example more precisely. x* is actually a2 in my code and I wrote something that is running:

`fun = @(Y, a2, x) (x - Y + a2 + a2 ./ (const1 * (const2 - a2)));' 
 'a1 = arrayfun(@(i) fzero(@(x) fun(Y(i), a2(i),x),[0, 0.999*min(const1, Y(i))]),1:numel(Y));`